# How to delete a particular row after it is fetched using SELECT query in SQL?

Tags: sql, fetch, row, sql-delete

How to delete a particular row after it is fetched using SELECT query in SQL?

```
DELETE row1 
FROM tablename 
WHEN fetched
```

Suppose,I fetch a row using SELECT query in SQL. Then I need to delete that row.
Is triggers are used for it? How? Please write the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "fetched"? Are you just wondering how to delete a row that meets certain criteria? Or do you mean that after you have loaded a row with a SELECT query, you want to be able to delete that same row?

Comment: use triggers!!!

Comment: Yes, delete a row after you have loaded with a SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL you can use CTE to delete a record when a select is performed. example is given below.

```
;WITH cte as (
  select clientid
 , status, Insertdate
      from Yourtable
 where clientid=1
 ) 
   delete from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the [output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) cause. Like this:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
DELETE TOP(1) dbo.DatabaseLog WITH (READPAST)  
OUTPUT deleted.*  
WHERE DatabaseLogID = 7;  
GO
```